# How to create a "modal" bottom banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the framework: MDB.

I would like to create a kind of div that is placed at the bottom and that when the user scrolls, continues to follow the page a bit like a sticky content.

On the MDB site, there is a solution that a modal bottom, which I could have opened automatically via JavaScript, without the user pressing on the button, the problem is that it completely obscures the `<body>`

[image]

How can I have this effect but without the blackout of the page?

Code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#frameModalBottom">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Frame Modal Bottom -->
<div class="modal fade bottom" id="frameModalBottom" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">

    <!-- Add class .modal-frame and then add class .modal-bottom (or other classes from list above) to set a position to the modal -->
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-frame modal-bottom" role="document">


        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

                    <p class="pt-3 pr-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit nisi quo
                        provident fugiat reprehenderit nostrum
                        quos..
                    </p>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Frame Modal Bottom -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.modal-backdrop {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by removing opacity of the black drop

```
.modal-backdrop
{
    opacity:0.5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create a kind of div that is placed at the bottom and that when the user scrolls, continues to follow the page a bit like a sticky content.

You can use `position:sticky` to make it sticky to the bottom... which is a "bit like sticky"

```css
#content {
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#bottom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="bottom">
  bottom
</div>
```

Fiddle if you prefer: https://jsfiddle.net/c0me5d63/

If you don't want to / can't use `position:sticky` then you can use `position:fixed`

```css
#content {
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

#bottom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="bottom">
  bottom
</div>
```